# ¿cómo mapear una llave compuesta (ID + FK) en JPA - Hibernate? (con pequeño plus)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

Me piden hacer este mapeo con JPA (lo marcado en rojo es para un pregunta plus) :D :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces hice esto:

GERENCIA CENTRAL

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gerencia_central")
public class GerenciaCentral implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_gerencia_c")
    private int gerenciaCenId;

    @Column(name = "codigo_gerencia_c_propio")
    private String codigoPropio;

    @Column(name = "descripcion_gerencia_c")
    private String descripcion;

    @Column(name = "descripcion_corta_gerencia_c")
    private String descripcionCorta;

    @Column(name = "estado_gerencia_c")
    private String estado;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gerenciaCen", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Gerencia> listaGerencia;
```

GERENCIA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gerencia")
public class Gerencia implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private GerenciaPK pk;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_gerencia_c", referencedColumnName = "id_gerencia_c", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private GerenciaCentral gerenciaCen;

    @Column(name = "codigo_gerencia_propio", length = 4)
    private String codigoPropio;

    @Column(name = "descripcion_gerencia", length = 80)
    private String descripcion;

    @Column(name = "descripcion_corta_gerencia", length = 40)
    private String descripcionCorta;

    @Column(name = "estado_gerencia", length = 1)
    private String estado;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gerencia", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AreaFuncional> listaAreafunc;
```

Y la llave de GERENCIA

```
@Embeddable
public class GerenciaPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "id_gerencia_c")
    private int gerenciaCenId;

    @Column(name = "id_gerencia")
    private int gerenciaId;
```

Está de más decir que todos tienen sus Get y Set y Equals y Hash Code. Aunque para el caso creo que nada de eso importa. Continuando...

Al ejecutar el proyecto me crea las tablas pero no las relaciones.

[image: Esquema generado por Mysql Workbench]

Muy bien. Cabe la posibilidad de que algo hice mal al generar el esquema. Por eso también revisé por otro medios.

[image: Buscando el FK]

[image: buscando el FK otra vez]

Y hasta generando el Scrip de la BD

```
CREATE TABLE `gerencia` (
 `id_gerencia_c` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_gerencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `codigo_gerencia_propio` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `descripcion_gerencia` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
 `descripcion_corta_gerencia` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `estado_gerencia` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_gerencia_c`,`id_gerencia`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Quisiera saber que está mal. No pregunto necesariamente que he hecho mal sino cualquier otra cosa que este mal. Hasta lo que me dieron para hacer.

**PREGUNTA PLUS**
En la primera imagen ven que resalto de rojo un casillero. Ahí me indican que sea entero pero de 4 dígitos. Como el primer ID debe ser "0001" yo cambie el entero por una cadena. Y el autoincremento ya corre por mi cuenta. Pero quisiera saber si hay manera de indicar todo eso al Hibernate para que guarde un número con ceros por delante. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto podría ayudarte, agregar

En GERENCIA CENTRAL:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to GERENCIA
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_gerencia_c")
    private Gerencia gerencia;
```

En GERENCIA

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to GerenciaCentral
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="gerencia")
    private List<GerenciaCentral> gerenciaCentrales;
```